# PHP Dateformat (11:00pm on April 24th)

Tags: php, date

I am trying to format the datetime

```
$TIME =  2013-04-24 23:00:00
date("g:ia \o\n\ F jS ", strtotime($TIME))
```

It shows the output as

```
11:00pm o April 24th
```

Why it doesn't show 'n'?

Comment: Because `"\n"` is a line break.

Comment: Would using `strftime` also be a good work alternative? It's a little like the opposite of `date`, instead of escaping chr's you don't want in the format of the date, you escape the ones you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
echo date("g:ia \o\\n\ F jS ", strtotime($TIME));
```

Basically u need to escape \n by using backslash() as it is a reserved keyword newline in php

Answer (score 1):

`\n` has special meaning inside double-quoted strings ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)). The simplest solution is to use single-quotes to delimit the string.

```
'g:ia \o\n F jS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use single quotes

```
$TIME = '2013-04-24 23:00:00';
date('g:ia \o\n F jS ', strtotime($TIME))
```

When used inside double quotes, `\n` is the character for a new line.

Comment: The `n` still needs to be escaped, since a plain letter `n` means "Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros".

Answer (score 0):

Just use single quotes instead of double quotes, because `\n` is interpreted as a newline when in a double quotes string, so do like this:

```
date('g:ia \o\n\ F jS ', strtotime($TIME))
```